# How to increase the indent size in (Cloud9)

Tags: layout, ide, indentation, cloud9-ide

In my cloud9 editor, I somehow have for some files that my indent is 3 characters and for others 7.

Is there a way to harmonize this and have the same indent everywhere? Is there perhaps also an auto-indent?

**Example of indent with 3 characters:**

```
function indent3() {
   // code here
}
```

**Example of indent with 7 characters:**

```
function indent7() {
       // code here
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can adjust the tab sizes by clicking near the bottom right of the editor for that file.

[image]

Comment: Set your preference as default be going to "Cloud9 -> Open Your Project Settings -> settings under `ace:`"

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to select preferences from the settings button in the upper right corner of the Cloud 9 user interface. This will take you to a GUI where you can set the project's default indent, so all its files have the same indent.

[Cloud 9 interface with settings button preferences in upper right, and on the left, changing the indent for a project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pw2Wg.jpg)