# How to change the tab size in Cloud9 editor

Tags: cloud9-ide, aws-cloud9

Does anyone know if Cloud9 stopped allowing users to change tab size inside editor? The buttons that existed on the bottom right (referenced in the link below) no longer exist

[How to increase the indent size in (Cloud9)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776297/how-to-increase-the-indent-size-in-cloud9)

Comment: You can still change tab size in "preferences".

Comment: @Riz I assume you mean the Code Editor (Ace) - soft tabs option, but that only sets the default tab size for new tabs - are you aware if there is still a way to change tab size for individual tabs?

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant but if you go to Preferences->Project settings, you can play with the options. I am not sure if you will get what you want. `Ace` has a website too which can help you as well. https://ace.c9.io/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like AWS fixed this bug on their own - the tab size buttons exist again in the editor